# RxSwift: how to build up the observable function call chain other than use callback?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, rx-swift

I'm trying to solve an async sequential problem, for example:

There are one 'OriginalData' in myclass, and I want to do some sequential operations to it: operationA, operationB and operationC:

operationA accepts OriginalData and return outputA, after it finishes, then operationB should take the outputA as input and return outputB, and move to operationC..

What I've done was using the callbacks:

```
// pseudocode
class Myclass {
    func operationA(inputA, callback: operationB)
    func operationB(inputB, callback: operationC)
    ..
}
```

As a result, if using callbacks, it will result in a callback hell and lots trouble. I turned into RxSwift, but not sure how to use RxSwift to solve it.

(P.S I've already read the RxSwift's official document, but still cannot make my idea clear. Best Appreciated for your helps!)

Comment: could you please explain lil bit more in code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem by using PublishSubject as follows:

```
let operationA = PublishSubject<String>()
let operationB = PublishSubject<String>()
let operationC = PublishSubject<String>()
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

operationA.asObserver()
    .subscribe(onNext:{element in
        operationB.onNext(element)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

operationB.asObserver()
    .subscribe(onNext:{element in
        operationC.onNext(element)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

operationC.asObserver()
    .subscribe(onNext:{element in
        print(element)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)


operationA.onNext("A")
```